# Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Linux 64-bit

Tags: ubuntu, node-sass

Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (93)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.13.1

i tried this one:
`run sudo npm rebuild node-sass`
but still not working

Answer (score 1):

Node-sass 4.14.1 isn't supported on Node 16 https://github.com/sass/node-sass#node-version-support-policy